# A Combinatorial Problem I

Tags: combinatorics

While I was trying to prove that if $X\sim$Negative Binomial$(r,p)$ and $Y\sim$Negative Binomial$(s,p)$ and $X,Y$ are independent then $X+Y\sim$Negative Binomial$(r+s,p)$, I came across that in order to prove this I have to prove $$\sum_{j=r}^{t-s}\binom{j-1}{r-1}\binom{t-j-1}{s-1}=\binom{t-1}{r+s-1}.$$ I have tried to give some combinatorial arguments but those do not seem so much worthy. I want to know how can I rigorously prove this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Notice that a negative binomial can be written as a sum of independent geometric random variables. This gives the simplest proof.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\sum_{j = r}^{t - s}{j - 1 \choose r - 1}
{t - j - 1 \choose s - 1}} =
\sum_{j = 0}^{t - s - r}{j + r - 1 \choose r - 1}{t - j - r - 1 \choose s - 1}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{j = 0}^{t - s - r}{j + r - 1 \choose j}
{t - j - r - 1 \choose t - j - r - s}
\\[5mm] &=
\sum_{j = 0}^{t - s - r}{-j - r + 1 + j - 1 \choose j}\pars{-1}^{j}
{-t + j + r + 1 + t - j - r - s - 1\choose t - j - r - s}\pars{-1}^{t - j - r - s}
\\[5mm] & =
\pars{-1}^{t - r - s}\,\,\,\,\sum_{j = 0}^{t - r - s}{-r \choose j}
{-s \choose t - r - s - j}
\\[5mm] & =
\color{#f00}{\pars{-1}^{n}\,\,\,\,\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}{-r \choose j}
{-s \choose n - j}}\,,\qquad\qquad
\bbox[#fee,10px,border:3px groove navy]{n \equiv t - r - s}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

With expression \eqref{1}:
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\sum_{j = r}^{t - s}{j - 1 \choose r - 1}
{t - j - 1 \choose s - 1}} =
\pars{-1}^{n}\,\,\,\,\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}{-r \choose j}
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}{\pars{1 + z}^{-s} \over z^{n - j + 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
\pars{-1}^{n}\,\,\,\,\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}
{\pars{1 + z}^{-s} \over z^{n + 1}}\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}{-r \choose j}z^{\, j}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\pars{-1}^{n}\,\,\,\,\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}
{\pars{1 + z}^{-s - r} \over z^{n + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
\pars{-1}^{n}{-r - s \choose n} =
\pars{-1}^{n}{r + s + n - 1 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n} =
{t - 1 \choose t - r - s}\qquad\pars{~\mbox{see}\ \eqref{1}~}
\\[5mm] & =
{t - 1 \choose \bracks{t - 1} - \bracks{t - r - s}} =
\color{#f00}{t - 1 \choose r + s - 1}
\end{align}